# How to implement a java IDE with Java

Tags: java, ide, implementation

I would know how to implement a Java IDE using Java language.

My IDE should :

- compile, run and debug a source code.
- import or export file from a directory.
- allow generating code from class diagram.
- allow modifying Java text editor.
- allow generate Swing source code from, I mean it will offer a ability of drag and drop, then it generates source code.
- it gives possibility to save, delete, undo and redo.
- it support JUnit, maven and Ant.

So, I ask about technologies that will help me to realize this Java IDE.  How to implement this IDE?

Comment: If you want to undertake such a task and have such a basic question , you probably aren't ready for it yet.

Comment: You definitely should use a Java IDE to program your Java IDE, IDEs are good technologies.

Comment: @Marcelo :"You definitely should use a Java IDE to program your Java IDE" :)) Nice !

Answer (score 1):

Except for the "drug" part which I am not sure of, I can tell it is not a trivial amount of work and of course I'd use the Java's GUI API
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29

Answer (score 1):

Will not be sarcastic like others around here so I will try to give a short answer.
Despite there are some very very mature Java IDE's (Eclipse,NetBeans,INtelliJ ,JCreator,Codeguide etc) around it is your right to do another (who know someday maybe better then existing ones).
This being said you can do it

- Swing (here you have to start from
  zero)
- use RCP Eclipse
- Netbeans platform
- QT it might be a solution
- etc.

All of this support drag and drop and have support for creting class diagrams...

I warn you it is not easy....not easy at all.
Eclipse was audited recently and it has apx. **46 millions** line of code
Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

I'd safe yourself loads of time and just use [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org) out of the box. Does everything you've listed and more. It's also free and has a module architecture to allow new functionality to be added fairly easily.